# Where should I put completer.complete() in this series of Future functions?

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

My function have to create a directory, and copy the entire folder hierarchy from another directory to this new one. All of the operation are done asynchronously, but I want this function to return a Future that when I call the .then(result) on it, will have done all of the asynchronously work.

But I don't know where exactly I should put my `completer.complete()` to achieve that.

```dart
Future<Directory> createCopyDirectory(Directory directoryToCreate){
  Completer<Directory> completer = new Completer<Directory>();
  completer.complete(
      directoryToCreate.create().then((directory){
        Directory contentToCopy = new Directory(globalPathOfDirectoryToCopy);
        List<Future> creatingContent = new List<Future>();
        contentToCopy.list(recursive:true, followLinks:false).forEach((f){
          if (f is File){
            File fileToCreate = new File(f.path.replaceFirst('pages', userID));
            creatingContent.add(fileToCreate.create(recursive:true).then((_){
              f.readAsString().then((fileContent){
                fileToCreate.writeAsString(fileContent);
              });
            }));
          }
        });
        return Future.wait(creatingContent).then((_){ return directoryToCreate;});
    })
  );
  return completer.future;
}
```

I precise that my function work like expected, But if I try to access directly the content I should have created in this function, like  in the `then()` call, Dart bring me an expection like I have not created the content. So the `completer.complete()` is surely badly placed and call `then()` before the content has been created.

I have tried with the `completer.complete()` on the ending `Future.wait(creatingContent)` or by replacing `return directoryToCreate` by `completer.complete(directoryToCreate)` but the result is the same.

I am a bit confused on the way to build a proper Future based function in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a `Completer` here.

```dart
Future<Directory> createCopyDirectory(Directory directoryToCreate) {
  return directoryToCreate.create().then((directory) {
    String userID = split(userDirectory.path).last;
    Directory contentToCopy = new Directory(globalPathOfDirectoryToCopy);
    List<Future> creatingContent = new List<Future>();
    return contentToCopy
        .list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
        .forEach((File f) {
      if (f is File) {
        File fileToCreate = new File(f.path.replaceFirst('pages', userID));
        creatingContent.add(fileToCreate.create(recursive: true).then((_) {
          return f.readAsString().then((fileContent) {
            return fileToCreate.writeAsString(fileContent);
          });
        }));
      }
    }).then((_) {
      return Future.wait(creatingContent).then((_) {
        return directoryToCreate;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Just to demonstrate how you could use the `Completer`:

```dart
Future<Directory> createCopyDirectory(Directory directoryToCreate) {
  Completer<Directory> completer = new Completer<Directory>();
  directoryToCreate.create().then((directory) {
    String userID = split(userDirectory.path).last;
    Directory contentToCopy = new Directory(globalPathOfDirectoryToCopy);
    List<Future> creatingContent = new List<Future>();
    contentToCopy.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false).forEach((f) {
      if (f is File) {
        File fileToCreate = new File(f.path.replaceFirst('pages', userID));
        creatingContent.add(fileToCreate.create(recursive: true).then((_) {
          return f.readAsString().then((fileContent) {
            return fileToCreate.writeAsString(fileContent);
          });
        }));
      }
    }).then((_) => Future
        .wait(creatingContent)
        .then((_) => completer.complete(directoryToCreate)));
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer (only the first part). with an additional `return` before `contentToCopy` and a `.then(...` at the end of the `foreEach`.

Comment: I have found it right when you have commented on it. Thanks a lot for your brain work, it motivated me to found the problem with more vigor.

Comment: I enjoyed it. It was quite an advanced async example and I learned something new myself :)